# Dynamically adding RangeValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add a RangeValidator into my ASPX upon runtime. I can create a RangeValidator with:

```
RangeValidator myval = new RangeValidator();
```

And add values to it. 
I can also access items on the page i.e.:

```
 HtmlTableRow myRow = (HtmlTableRow)Page.FindControl("page1").FindControl("tr-row");
 myRow .Controls.Add(myval);
```

I cant add a rangevalidator here though as "TR can not accept children controls of this type. Where can I add it? I cant add it to my pages main form as I have ASPX code blocks which will fall over if I use runat=server for the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add that control to a `<td>` or to a [Placeholder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx) that's in a correct spot.

Comment: Damn, seems logical. Not sure why I even thought I could append it to the TR row... *facepalm*